# C# to VB.net delegate conversiom

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying convert C# code to VB.net and delegate stopped me.

origial code is:

```
using (var source = new ETWTraceEventSource(sessionName, TraceEventSourceType.Session))
        {
            Action<TraceEvent> action = delegate (TraceEvent data)
            {
                var taskName = data.TaskName;
                var EventName = data.EventName;
```

Row Action<>... is problem for me.
Some example will be appreciated.
Thanks, Jerry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the 'delegate' keyword in this way is outdated legacy C# (pre-lambda operator). The modern C# way is to use the lambda operator:

```
Action<TraceEvent> action = (TraceEvent data) =>
```

The VB equivalent for both is:

```
Option Infer On

Using source = New ETWTraceEventSource(sessionName, TraceEventSourceType.Session)
    Dim action As Action(Of TraceEvent) = Sub(data As TraceEvent)
        Dim taskName = data.TaskName
        Dim EventName = data.EventName
    End Sub
End Using
```